# php stdClass object value

Tags: php, stdclass

I have the following stdClass:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["3afa3501461570b33a8f8efeae4faa39"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["filename"]=>
    string(36) "3afa3501461570b33a8f8efeae4faa39.jpg"
    ["alt"]=>
    string(23) "Kismama Párna Virágos"
    ["caption"]=>
    string(1008) " Ez az egyedülálló, ergonómikus kialakítású párna, a babákat a megfelelő magasságba, és pozícióba helyezésével segíti, és kényelmesebbé teszi a kisbabák etetését 

  • Tartós, minőségi anyag
 • Könnyen újratölthető
 • Egyszerűen tisztítható
 •  Antiallergén, gyerekbarát

 Anyaga: mosható, 100 % pamutvászon (belső), 100% mosható pamut(külső) 

  Mérete:120x40 cm  

 Az ár bruttó ár, mely tartalmazza a 27% Áfá-t 

  Szállítási idő: 1-3 hét

"
  }
```

I would like access only the [filename] value but `$var->filename;` not working, i get the following error:  `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$filename in`.

The `stdClass name ["3afa3501461570b33a8f8efeae4faa39"]` is randomly every mysql rows.

thank you for your help!

Comment: $var->3afa3501461570b33a8f8efeae4faa39->filename

Comment: this cause he following error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or ' (the "3afa3501461570b33a8f8efeae4faa39" is an random number, beacuse CI is coded when save to database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?php
foreach($object as $file){}
echo $file->filename;
?>
```

or

```
<?php    
echo $object->{end(array_keys((array)$object))}->filename;
?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/201681

Comment: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in